# How Can I Bring 2 Separate Float's Together?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have 2 floats, one on the left side of the screen and one right. My goal is to move the left float to the right side of the screen, but without moving it to the right side of my other float. I am unable to change their order in the HTML, so the first float is currently taking precedence. Am I overlooking something? If not, what alternatives do I have?

**jsFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/h7y9bwre/

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Section 1 -->
<div class="left">
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Other Stuff</p>
</div>

<!-- Section 2 -->
<div class="right">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
</div>
```

*"Section 1" has to stay above "Section 2" in the HTML.*

**Currently:**
[image: Currently]

**Goal:**
[image: Goal]

Comment: i think you  wan to this http://jsfiddle.net/h7y9bwre/3/

Comment: Add a picture how you want.

Comment: Are you able to remove the current css?

Comment: I can't remove it, but I can override it

Comment: check my updated answer demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use floats for this. Just set wrappers as inline-blocks and align them into the right.

```css
.right,
.left {
  display: inline-block;
}
#bar-container {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the current CSS to let the `<div>`s align to the right by making them `inline-block`.

```css
#bar-container {width: 100%;}
.left, .right {width: 50%;}
.left {float: left;}
.right {float: right; }

p {display: inline-block; padding: 0 1%}

.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */


/**
 * YOUR STYLES
 */



#bar-container {
  text-align: right;
}

.left, .right {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: auto;
}

.left {
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar-container" class="clearfix">
    <div class="left">
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <p>Other Stuff</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="right">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Edit: Make sure the old CSS is still there, as you can't delete it.

Answer (score 2):

`flexbox` can do that

```css
#bar-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
#bar-container div {
    border:1px solid red;
}
p {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="bar-container" class="clearfix">
    <div class="left">
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <p>Other Stuff</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
        <img src="http://placehold.it/30x30" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your picture, you can do like this:

```
#bar-container{
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h7y9bwre/7/)

Comment: Adding `float: right` there moves `.left` past `.right`. I need it to stay on the left side of `.right` if that makes sense

Comment: I need `.right` to stay further right than `.left`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the floats in your css.

Instead of:

```
.left {float: left;}
.right {float: right; }
```

Invert it:

```
.left {float: right;}
.right {float: left; }
```

*Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/h7y9bwre/1/*

---

**Edit** (based on Op's edit to question):

Change the percent width and margins of your divs. Currently, they are `50%` of the entire width. Change to:

```
.left, .right {width: 25%;}
.left {float: left; margin-left: 50%;}
.right {float: right; }
```

**Fiddle 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/h7y9bwre/5/**

Comment: That's not what OP expects to do. OP wants to override the css.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal: Thank you for the downvote. But, please let me know where does the Op say that *wants to override the css*. And what is wrong with this answer?

Comment: Sorry, that was by mistake (undownvoted). But you should at least know semantically .left class setting to `float:right` is not good...

Comment: @BhojendraNepal: Thanks.

Comment: he dont want one div at left and another at right, he wants BOTH right side but in inverted order

Comment: @Pepo_rasta: Thank you for the comment. Let's let the Op decide.

Answer (score 0):

Hi now define your **class** `.left`  `float: right; margin-left:50%;`

**as like this**

```
#bar-container .left{
    float: left;
    width:25%;
    margin-left:50%; 
}
#bar-container .right{

    width:25%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just change .right css with

```
position:relative;
top:100px;
left:300px;
```

I have update jsFiddle: the http://jsfiddle.net/h7y9bwre/4/
Don't know if that is what you want.
Hope it is helpful.